# Issue with pointer to char

Tags: c

What seems to be the problem with this part of my code:

```
while(c != EOF){    
    c = fgetc(myFile);
    p[i++]=c;
    printf("%c", p[i]);
}
```

It does not seem to store the values in `p[i]` even though malloc succeeds, and prints garbage. However this code prints the characters fine:

```
while(c != EOF){    
    c = fgetc(myFile);
    //p[i++]=c;
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

`p` is a `char*` and `i` is initially `0`.
Asked in the question [Not getting all characters after reading from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763025/not-getting-all-characters-after-reading-from-file)

What is the problem here?

Comment: It would make it easier for people here to answer your questions if you formatted them before posting. Any consistent style will do ;)

Comment: The indentation was really strange (indentation of 3-7 spaces, sometimes indenting `if`/`else`, sometimes not, etc.). Most editors will do auto-indentation.

Comment: @BrendanLong: Fingers do it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `p[i++] = c` stores the character and increments `i`. The next line prints `p[i]`but i **has already been incremented**. Try this:

```
while(c!=EOF){    
    c=fgetc(myFile);
    p[i]=c;
    printf("%c",p[i]);

    i++;
}
```

As a side note, you could probably rewrite it

```
while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
    *p++ = c;
```

Comment: NO... i allocated `char *p=(char *)malloc((count+1));` - in fact even `char *p=(char *)malloc((count*2));` this does not solve my problem.. `count` is the total no. of chars in the file.

Comment: @cnicutar - `while(c!=EOF){    
                         c=fgetc(myFile);
                         p[i]=c;
                         printf("%c",p[i++]);
                         ;
                         }` this does it as well thanks :)

Comment: @Lohit At first I assumed you didn't allocate memory. Then I spotted `i++` so I edited.

Answer (score 0):

problem is,

```
while(c!=EOF){    
              c=fgetc(myFile);
              p[i++]=c;
              printf("%c",p[i]);
             }
```

look at the p[i++]=c, it stores the value of c in p[i] than increments i by one,
so when you use p[i] to print the character you are referring to another memory location which possibly holds garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `i` after you store the char, so you are printing the next position, which you haven't stored anything to yet.

change the lines to:

```
p[i]=c;
printf("%c",p[i++]);
```